How can I read out the dignostic addresses of profibus DP slaves connected to a Siemens S7-300 PLC?
I am reading currently system status informations of a S7-300 over SFC51 RDSYSST function. But here I have one problem. When I want o read out the diagnostic data of DP slaves I have to define when using RDSYSST, the SSL ID as 0x00B4 and the index as the diagnostic address of the related slave.
Normaly Here I should look to the machine's PLC Hardware configuration and find the diagnostic address accordingly. But in my use case I am connecting to a machine where I do not have these informations. So I need to read out first the diagnostic addresses of the slaves. How can I do it with RDSYSST or any other system function?
Normaly it is possible to get the profibus addresses of all slaves with SSL ID 0x0092. But the diagnostic addresses are not given here.

The information about this is intrinsic, so it is perfectly difficult to find. According to SFC51  documentation, there are 0x00B[x] - the family of the status list generation modes that allows to find diagnostic information about the module.
I also uploaded the printed PDF version of the SFC51 help page here. Maybe, it would be helpful.
